# What is the difference Helix vs Perforce?

Tags: perforce, helix

I am working in a project which was using the **Perforce** repository. So I was using **P4** and **P4V** tools, to make commits and submissions. Now I decided to make my machine cleaner, so I reinstalled the Ubuntu, and making new settings.

Installing the P4 and P4V, made me a little confused. 
I can install next things, to get the **p4** tool:

```
$ sudo apt-get install perforce-cli
```

and

```
$ sudo apt-get install helix-cli
```

So the question is what is the difference betwen helix-* products and perforce-*. 
Is it just new\old names? perforce-*** has more things that can be installed

Comment: It's a naming/marketing thing. The company builds more tools than just p4/p4d/p4v nowadays (there are code review tools, git tools, etc.) Helix is an umbrella brand name of sorts, I suppose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Helix is the new name that we have given to some Perforce Products.

i.e., Helix Server = P4D = Perforce Server

Helix CLI = P4 = Perforce Command Line client.

To install the latest version of the Helix Server (Perforce Server) and Helix command line client (P4) using packages, run:

```
sudo aptitude install helix-p4d helix-cli
```